# How to enable HBase dynamic configuration?

Tags: hbase

I want to enable dynamic configuration in HBase so that I do not have to restart HBase whenever I make configuration changes.

https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#dyn_config

I referred to the above link, but it does not explain how exactly do we update configs without having to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the configuration properties supports for dynamic changes as mentioned here https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#dyn_config. 
To update the configurations dynamically,

1. Update the values of the configuration properties which you want to update in the ***hbase-site.xml*** file.
2. Login into ***(HBASE_HOME)/bin/hbase shell***
3. Execute the following commands accordingly, if you want to just update the configurations in one server then execute ***update_config '(SERVER_NAME)'*** and if you want to update in all the hbase servers then execute ***update_all_config*** command.